# Autosizing Winform with a docked datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview docked in a form and I want to be able to have the form and grid auto size themselves to fit.  I have both the form and grid set to autosize but I keep having a "margin" and the right and bottom of the form/grid.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

What I would like is to have the to gray areas on the right and bottom gone and I cannot seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a simple way of getting the grid height width of the internals but, you could do something like this:

```
int gridWidth = 0;
int gridHeight = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    gridWidth += col.Width;
}
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    gridHeight += row.Height;
}
```

after that, just tie into an event on the grid when the contents change, get the new height and width and rezise the form with those values (and some padding of course)

Comment: It's sizes right.  But what I'm looking for is for the form to shrink to cover that area.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
detailsDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That fixes it.  Thanks.